# Blocks in Ruby, Error:Wrong Number of arguments

Tags: ruby

```
def power(a,b)
    puts" #{a}**#{b} is"
    yield a,b
    puts"Program Terminating..."
end

power {|a,b| printf "#{a**b}" }

power(2,3)
```

The expected output should be `8`.

Error message:

> `power': #wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

I want to use a block with multiple parameters that is invoked from a method that accepts two arguments.

Answer (score 8):

You basically have two calls to `power` without any reason (I’d wild guess you expected kinda currying there, but it’s not how currying is done in ruby.)

The first call to `power` with a block does not pass any argument, while both regular arguments are mandatory. There should be a single call, passing both a block *and* arguments:

```
power(2, 3) { |a, b| print "#{a**b}" }
```